# What definition files to install when begining a project with typescript ? Error Cannot find name 'console'

Tags: meteor, typescript

I am new to typescript in Meteor and following [this guide](https://atmospherejs.com/barbatus/typescript) I have an error with console.log `Cannot find name 'console'`

What definitions files have I to install to avoid this (and futur) common errors?

Comment: Can you share your Typescript compiler options?

Comment: I am not sure where is it. The guide states that the compiler option looks like : {
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "es5",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "sourceMap": true
}

Comment: I have also a file in my root folder with this inside: {
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654"
  }
}

Comment: I thought it was "noLib" option ("Do not include the default library file (lib.d.ts)"), but I've mistaken. Your config looks ok for me.